# Triangle inscribed in a circle - maximize $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$.

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

I am interested in the following problem:

> What is maximum value of $a^2 +b^2+c^2$, where $a,b,c$ are sides of a
>   triangle inscribed in a unit circle?

I know that this problem can be solved using multivariate analysis, e.g by Lagrange multipliers, etc.
But this is a problem for high-school level math circle. That is why I would like to find out how to use elementary plane geometry ideas to solve it efficiently.

I believe that correct answer is equilateral  triangle. I will be glad for solutions or hints.

Comment: I guess a first step might be to prove that an isosceles triangle has more area than any of the other triangles where the base leg is fixed and the opposite point is moved along the circle.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939902/alternate-proof-for-a2b2c2-le-9r2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using complex numbers. The unit circle is defined by equation $z\bar{z}=1$ and the three vertices of the triangle is $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}&=(z_{1}-z_{2})(\bar{z_{1}}-\bar{z_{2}})+(z_{2}-z_{3})(\bar{z_{2}}-\bar{z_{3}})+(z_{3}-z_{1})(\bar{z_{3}}-\bar{z_{1}})\\
&=9-(z_{1}+z_{2}+z_{3})(\bar{z_{1}}+\bar{z_{2}}+\bar{z_{3}})\\
&\leq 9
\end{aligned}
$$

$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$ is maximum when the triangle’s circumcenter coincides with its centroid i.e. when the triangle is equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

The hint:

Use $$S=\frac{abc}{4R}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}$$
and prove that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\leq9R^2.$$
Finally, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^6-a^4b^2-a^4c^2+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$ which is true by Schur.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the following way.

In the standard notation we'll prove that:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\leq9R^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}4R^2\sin^2\alpha\leq9R^2$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}(1-\cos2\alpha)\leq9$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}\cos2\alpha\geq-3$$ or
$$2(2\cos^2\alpha-1)+4\cos(\beta+\gamma)\cos(\beta-\gamma)\geq-3$$ or
$$4\cos^2\alpha-4\cos(\beta-\gamma)\cos\alpha+1\geq0$$ or
$$(2\cos\alpha-\cos(\beta-\gamma))^2+\sin^2(\beta-\gamma)\geq0,$$ the equality occurs for the equilateral triangle, which says that $9$ is a maximal value.